# What is the right way to re-partition a disk with already installed linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, lvm

What is the right way to fully re-partition my HDD (on a VPS -> no access to hardware), if there is currently installed a Debian Squeeze? I would like to create all encrypted LVM partitions, e.g.:

```
Physical:
-/boot
-swap

LVM:
-/
-/home
-/var
-/var/log
-/tmp
```

P.S. There is NO data I care about (even the OS).

Comment: What is your question, it isn't clear?  If you are going to wipe the installation, then you boot the VPS with the debian install disk and set up your partitioning during installation.

Comment: I didn't get how to do the partitioning scheme, as described above and set one of LVM encrypted partition to root (it is possible either normal `ext2/3` or `physical encrypted partition`). Thats why I installed temporary Debian base system to re-partition it from the normal linux environment and not from the busybox one, where I needed to install all the staff (including fdisk, dpkg and apt-get myself). I don't know what did I wrong, but it was a kind of nightmare to handle one error after another and getting forward with millimeter steps.

Comment: I see. If you have space, then you can create a new partition and dm-crypt it, then duplicate your LVM volumes on it, and rsync each volume over to it.  And update fstab on the new root.  Then it is just a case of creating a new entry in grub has root pointing to the new encrypted root volume rather than the old one. If it doesn't work, you can boot the old one to figure it out.